# Windows HDR and screenshots

Tags: windows, screenshot, windows-11, hdr

When I take screenshots with HDR enabled in Windows 11 21H2, they are washed out.

This is whether I take them with PRNTSCRN or I use the Snipping Tool.

Is there a solution to this problem other then temporarily disabling HDR?

Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I'd permanently disable HDR. I could go on at length as to why it's one of the worst 'improvements' to computer screen technology since the LCD display, but there really isn't room. With it on, nothing you see is real.

Comment: I agree with the above. Also you can consider this article to see if it helps.   https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ca/000143830/colors-are-faded-and-washed-out-when-high-dynamic-range-is-enabled-in-windows-10     .   I use Snipping Tool and Snagit and no washouts at all.

Comment: Do you paste the screenshot data into a program that can understand HDR data and present it as HDR? If not, the program will show the pasted data in SDR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I take screenshots with HDR enabled in Windows 11 21H2, they are washed out.  Is there a solution to this problem other then temporarily disabling HDR?

The behavior you describe is a known current issue with Windows 11 21H2.  The simplest solution, is to live with the behavior, until it can be patched later this month. The alternative to that would be to downgrade to Windows 10 21H2, which would involve a complete reinstall of Windows, which seems a little overkill for a temporary problem that should be fixed within 2 weeks.

> After installing Windows 11, some image editing programs might not
> render colors correctly on certain HDR displays. This is frequently
> observed with white colors, which could display in bright yellow or
> other colors.
>
> This issue occurs when certain color-rendering Win32 APIs return
> unexpected information or errors under specific conditions. Not all
> color profile management programs are affected, and color profile
> options available in the Windows 11 Settings page, including Microsoft
> Color Control Panel, are expected to function correctly.
>
> Next steps: We are working on a resolution and estimate a solution
> will be available in late January.

Source: [Applications using Win32 APIs to render colors might not work as expected](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-11-21h2#december-2021)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks.  Seems like you may have some inside info here.  Very helpful.

Comment: What inside information.  I just performed research

Comment: The problem exists in Windows 10 21H2 as well...

Comment: yes this has not been fixed as of March 24th 2012 :(

Comment: [Microsoft reports this was resolved back on January 25th 2022](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/january-25-2022-kb5008353-os-build-22000-469-preview-920e6297-567b-4b95-afe9-35d17de02c3a). “Updates a known issue that might prevent some image editing programs from rendering colors correctly on certain high dynamic range (HDR) displays. This frequently affects white colors that might display in bright yellow or other colors.”

Comment: this is still happening in April on Windows 11 Pro 21H2. Everything up to date via Windows update.

Comment: @gian1200 - Your only recourse is to report  the issue to Microsoft

Comment: This is still happening on Windows 11 22H2, October 2022. Just updated yesterday.

Comment: @Jeffmagma - Report it to Microsoft.  Based on the information I have access to this issue has already been resolved. Perhaps the software that still has the problem need to be updated.

Comment: @jTiKey - As I suggested 2 years ago.  You should report it to Microsoft but it’s unlikely to be the same exact problem they reported as being resolved