# Potplayer screenshot color different from real

Tags: colors, daum-pot-player

1. I use shortcut `ctrl+c` to take screenshot in potplayer :

[image]

This is not the color I saw on my monitor !

2. I use another screenshot software take :

[image]

This is what I saw on monitor.

How can I make potplayer take screenshot as what I see ?

---

It looks like potplay do something, may be use some filters ? I don't quite understand the tech undergroud sorry .

Comment: Do you have an HDR monitor?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1698694/windows-hdr-and-screenshots

Comment: @Mokubai No , I tried two monitors both have same problem.  And Windows show the color space is SDR.

Comment: @Mokubai If I have HDR problem , I think I could never take the second screenshot .

Comment: What about the video you are playing? Is it HDR10 and potplayer has some bug in it's screenshot tool that is mis-converting the colourspace to SDR while the player is not...

Comment: @Mokubai Nope, it's normal video . Yeah I know the bug,  I have saw the HDR video would looks uncorrectly(more green) when play by potplayer . The screenshots I posted at least look correct , may be potplayer add some color to original , so it looks better ?

Comment: It looks like a gamma shift rather than a colour shift - one might be incorrectly interpreting Rec709 as sRGB. You'd have to examine the colour profiles attached to the movie & both images. Images uploaded here by imgur all have their profiles & other metadata stripped so we can't look at them once posted here.

Comment: Rec 709 vs sRGB may as well be rocket science. tbh, I don't fully get it myself, you need a video expert for that; but to oversimplify, they have 'the same colours but a different gamma curve'. If you want to see how it also confuses other people, read https://community.adobe.com/t5/after-effects-discussions/rec709-and-srgb-no-color-management-difference/m-p/5133246 & then 2/3 down the 'full rocket science' explanation which begins "Pedantry ahead!" […and this is before you get anywhere near 'HDR' which uses Rec 2020 or P3 & is even more complicated;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having the same problem with *Cyberpunk Edgerunners* screenshots.

If you have potplayer's **HDR to SDR** feature turned on, the image will be as nice as your second image. This feature adjusts the colour of the video to make it look a little more correct on an SDR monitor (but in reality it is nowhere near the correct HDR colour, even though it looks good).

Or maybe you have an HDR monitor and something goes wrong when you save the screenshot as a JPEG. the JPEG may only save the SDR image and when it tries to save the HDR image it will interpret it as an SDR image format and the image becomes grey.

The way I did it was to convert the *Cuberpunk Edgerunners* video to a new video file in SDR colours using **ffmpeg**. Then I took a screenshot on the new video.

Or you can take the image you have already captured and fix it with image processing software.

You could download the compiled ffmpeg executable from the internet. And I used the following code to transcode the HDR video to SDR video:

```
param ([string]$filename)

./ffmpeg.exe `
-hwaccel cuda `
-c:v hevc_cuvid `
-i $filename `
-vf zscale=t=linear:npl=100,format=gbrpf32le,zscale=p=bt709,tonemap=tonemap=hable:desat=0,zscale=t=bt709:m=bt709:r=tv,format=yuv420p `
-c:v h264_nvenc `
-preset slow `
-crf 18 `
-c:a copy `
-c:s copy `
./sdr/$filename
```

Save the code in .ps1 format. Place it in your video directory. Put the ffmpeg.exe in the same place. In a blank area of this directory's window use shift + right mouse click to open powershell. start with

```
 .\[your ps1 file name].ps1 [your video name].mkv
```

to execute it.

Both of these methods will reduce the HDR image to an SDR image. However if you watch Cyberpunk Edgerunners via Netflix streaming, you don't get the .mkv file, so you can't transcode it to an SDR video file with ffmpeg. Maybe you should try Google to find a way to save HDR images in the correct format. JPEG doesn't achieve this.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: Wow ,  I think you are right . Thank you for point out the problem come from. Acually I have gave up using `ctrl+c` , because I can't wait to use LUCY as my phone backgroud . I have used another softeware take the pictures